# Prevent loading page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller create and return content where it triggers an alert.
The problem it load an empty page. How can I prevent it to load an empty page and stays in the current view and do nothing just pop the alert.

What I really wanted here is before the user can create new data, it will validate first if the `diseaseID` is already existing for specific `assessmentID`, and when the result is null, it will just pop an alert and do nothing. But here I'm just trying make `alert()` work properly.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateDisease(int? diseaseID,int? assessmentID, DiseaseList diseaselist)
    {
        diseaselist.DiseaseID = diseaseID;
        diseaselist.AssessmentID = assessmentID;
        db.DiseaseLists.Add(diseaselist);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Item already exist');</script>");

    }
```

Comment: You can wrap the message in a `ViewBag` or a viewmodel then use `alert` with JS in client-side code if the message exists.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I edited the content.

Comment: Rather than returning `Content` in GET method, try using `return View("Disease")` to show same view instead. Client-side validation can be handled using AJAX with `DiseaseID` as parameter, pass it to controller action which returns validation message if exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to return the script as content from the controller, just return the values as json that will tell you that the item already exist and based on that true or false value show an alert from the client side js.

your controller code will look something like this

```
diseaseModel.DiseaseID = diseaseID;
diseaseModel.AssessmentID = assessmentID;
diseaseModel.AlreadyExist = true;

return Json(diseaseModel);
```